# Will the getInstalledPackages method be affected on the Android 11 platform?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

I tried to use the getInstalledPackages method on Meizu 18 (Android 11), but it returned me an empty list. However, this problem does not exist on Meizu 17 (Android 10). I hope someone can help me solve it, thanks

```
val packages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
```

Comment: Google for package visibility.

Comment: The document indicates that the three methods queryIntentActivities(), getPackageInfo(), and getInstalledApplications() will be affected, but I am not sure if the problem I encountered is related to this limitation

Comment: No need to be shure of that. Instead apply the needed permissions. Try, try and try.